# clear the Visual Studio OUTPUT window programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

is it possible to have a way to clear the Visual Studio OUTPUT window, programmatically for a C++ program? Today I use OutputDebugString call to write there, and at some point I want to clear it. Is this possible?

I use VS2008

Comment: Not sure why you think it's any of the program's business what the output window does.

Comment: While debugging - I am writing comments there - using OutputDebugString call. at some points I want want to clear it.

Comment: @DuduArbel Deleted my answer as it is not quite related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Simply because OutputDebugString is not related at all to the Visual Studio output window itself. This output window just happens to be a listener for this kind of messages. There are other listeners like DebugView. But there's no message like "forget all previous messages".

If you absolutely need such "feature" you may think about logging to a seperate console window and clean this like desribed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261/EN-US

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer, but it's not what you really want.

```
printf("\f");
```

will print a form feed to the console. That is supposed to clear it. In fact modern consoles store histories which are hard to clear in a definite way.